# Google WebRTC. 'out/Release/' - No such directory

Tags: webrtc, ninja

I try build required libraries Google WebRTC on this article http://www.medooze.com/products/media-mixer-server/installation.aspx

I have done:

```
svn co http://src.chromium.org/chrome/trunk/tools/depot_tools
export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/src/depot_tools

mkdir webrtc
cd webrtc
gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
gclient sync --force
gclient runhooks --force
cd trunk

ninja -C out/Release/ common_audio
```

**Error:**

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/Release/'
ninja: fatal: chdir to 'out/Release/' - No such file or directory
```

Please help on this error.

Comment: are you running ninja from the webrtc trunk directory? or its parent directory?

Comment: Im sorry. Error fixed. Need make gclient sync --force for finish.

Comment: @AntonPatsev: how you fixed the issue exactly ?

Comment: @Ankit yesterday I dont check. In dont know